# Make auto-update network-dependent

Tags: wireless, updates

I'd like to restrict downloads in Ubuntu when it is connected to my phone for wifi, in particular disable auto-update when on this particular network. Any ideas?

Comment: Network Manager has a "metered connection" setting specifically for the purpose of preventing big data-charge surprises.

Comment: Thanks @user535733, found it in Settings / Wi-Fi for the specific network connection.